# Random sample generated for i.i.d variables

Tags: probability-theory, statistical-inference, exponential-distribution, simulation

**My attempt:** Since $f(y;a) = \frac{1}{2a}exp(\frac{-y}{2a})$ for $y>0$, and $f(y;a) = \frac{1}{2a}exp(\frac{y}{2a})$ for $y<0$, it is easy to see $A_n$ is a sufficient statistics for a family $T$ of measure $\left\{f(y;a): x, a > 0\right\}$. This means when generating a sample that is **equivalent to** $Y_1, Y_2,\ldots Y_n$, we only care about the information of $\sum_{i=1}^{n} S_1+\ldots + S_n = A_n$.

Comment: Since $S_1 = A_1$ needs to have the same distribution as $Y_1$, the distribution of the iid sequence $(S_n)_n$ is uniquely determined.

Comment: When you say "it is easy to see $A_n$ is a sufficient statistic" - I think you have misunderstood the notion of sufficient statistic. You need to at least consider the joint distribution. I would be surprised if $A_n$ was sufficient for sums of i.i.d Laplace distributed variables. Are you sure the question isn't supposed to be about the exponential distribution? Or maybe $A_n=\sum_{i=1}^n|Y_i|$?

Comment: @Dap: Thanks for your help. I fixed the density. I did multiply them to get the joint distribution, but then we would see the sum is either + or - depending on the sign of $X_1$ (since Xs are i.i.d). So I am not sure why you said $A_n$ is not sufficient? $A_n$ was given in the original problem, but the sufficient part is my comment. So I guess $T_n = \sum_{i=1}^{n} |Y_n|$ are sufficient for $f(Y; a)$ we just need to generate $n$ random samples having $T_n = +/-A_n$ for any $n$?

Comment: I said that because I'm pretty sure the joint pdf $(\tfrac 1 {2a})^n\exp(-\tfrac 1 a\sum_{i=1}^n|y_i|)$ doesn't factor as $h(y)g_a(\sum_{i=1}^n y_i).$ It obviously does factor though your $T_n$ though, and the problem would be much much easier with $T_n.$ I can't work out what you might mean by $T_n=\pm A_n,$ obviously $|1|+|-1|$ isn't $\pm (1+(-1))$ for example.

Comment: @Dap: Yeap, you interpreted $T_n = +/- A_n$ correctly. So could you please show me how you would solve this problem? Because all we are given is $A_n$, not the sign of each variable $Y_i$. So if we could find a sample of i.i.d $S_i$ such that $\sum_{i=1}^n S_i = T_n$ and record all the $\sum_{i=1}^n sgn*S_i = A_n$ where $sgn = 1$ or $-1$ (basically, brute-forcing here with the signs!), then we obtain a sample of $S_1, S_2,\ldots, S_n$ that is equivalent to $X_1, X_2,\ldots, X_n$. Would this be correct?

Comment: @user177196: $\tfrac {1}{2a}\exp(-|y|/2a)$ isn't a pdf; it integrates to $2.$ What is the original problem?

Comment: @Dap: that's the original problem. So the original pdf is wrong;( I guess we just work with $f(x;a) = \frac{1}{2a}exp(\frac{-|x|}{a})$. Could you address the three questions in my three latest comments below your "solution"?

Comment: Have pity on your Readers who have to guess what you are really asking and put an explicit statement of the problem you want help with in the body of the Question.  Limiting the problem statement to the title (if that's what you did here) invites confusion because the title is necessarily a brief text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your last question is answered by saz in the comments.

Here is one approach to the problem. It's not really related to the hints though.

I take the problem to be sample from the conditional distribution of $Y_1,\dots,Y_n,$ given the sum $A_i=\sum_{i=1}^nY_i.$ I will treat this as a reasonable practical problem, where integrating an $n-1$-dimensional conditional pdf is too slow.

First recall (or read on Wikipedia) that $Y_i$ has the same distribution as $X_i-X'_i$ where $X_i,X'_i$ are independent $\mathrm{Exp}(1/a)$ variables. And $B_n=\sum_{i=1}^n X_i$ and $B'_n=\sum_{i=1}^n X'_i$ have independent $\mathrm{Erlang}(n, 1/a)$ distribution, also known as a gamma distribution.

Since $A_n=B_n-B'_n,$ we can think of $A_n$ as a difference of independent $\mathrm{Erlang}(n, 1/a)$ distributed variables. The conditional pdf of $B_n$ is given by

$$f_{B_n|A_n}(x)\propto x^{n-1}e^{-x/a} \cdot
(x-A_n)^{n-1}e^{-(x-A_n)/a} 
$$

for $x\geq A_n.$

This is not a common distribution. One way to sample from it would be to use the binomial expansion

$$x^{n-1}(x-A_n)^{n-1}=(x-A_n+A_n)^{n-1}(x-A_n)^{n-1}=\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}\binom{n-1}{j}(x-A_n)^{n+j}A_n^{n-1-j}$$

which reduces to sampling from a mix of Erlang (i.e. gamma) distributions. (More explanation below)

We can then sample $X_1,\dots,X_n$ conditioned on $B_i,$ which is much easier (see below). Similarly for $X'_1,\dots,X'_n.$ The differences $Y_i=X_i-X'_i$ will then have the correct distribution conditioned on $A_i.$

#### Sampling from i.i.d. exponentials conditioned on their sum

As mentioned in the comments, the joint pdf of $X_1,…,X_N$ conditioned on their sum $B_i$ is uniform on $\{X_1+\cdots+X_n=B_i\}$. This uniform distribution is homogeneous in $B_i$ - it doesn't depend on $B_i$ except for scaling - so you can just sample i.i.d exponential variables $X_1+\cdots+X_n$ and scale them to have sum $B_i$.

#### Sampling from a mixture of distributions

It is possible to efficiently sample from a pdf of the form

$$f(x) \propto \sum_{j=0}^{n-1} f_j(x)$$

as long as the integrals $Z_j=\int f_j(x)$ can be computed efficiently. For the case in question $Z_j$ can be expressed in terms of factorials and simple expressions of $a$ and $A_n.$ The marginal pdf of $j$ is given by $Z_j/(Z_0+\dots+Z_{n-1}).$ This involves sampling from a custom pdf, but it's just $n$ different values so can be computed quite quickly. Given $j$, the condition distribution of $x$ is given by $f(x\mid j)=f_j(x),$ e.g. a gamma distribution.

Comment: thank you so much for your detailed approach. It is much more complicated then what I thought. I have a couple of questions: 
(1) How do you actually sample $X_1,\ldots, X_n$ conditioned on $B_i$ in Python (or R) though? 
(2) Why $A_n = B_n - B'_n$?? Is it just our made-up condition, as we only know that $Y_i$ has the same pdf as $X_i - X'_i$?
(3) For the last step, sampling $X_1,\ldots, X_n$ given $B_i$, could you elaborate on how we could implement this in Python?

Comment: Also, I think we are only given $A_n$ for some fixed n. We won't know the pdf of $X_i$ in real-world (or do we know, from the problem context?), but we have to generate the sample that matches the given exponential distribution of $X_i$.

Comment: From your derivation, $f_{B_n|A_n}(x)\propto e^{-2x/a+A_n/a}\sum_{j=0}^{n-1} {n-1 \choose j} (x-A_n)^{n+j}A_n^{n-1-j}$. How is the RHS a gamma distribution?

Comment: (1&3): the joint pdf of $X_1,\dots,X_N$ conditioned on $B_i$ is uniform on $X_1+\dots+X_n=B_i.$ So you can just sample i.i.d exponential variables $X_1,\dots,X_n$ and scale them to have sum $B_i.$ (2) Basically by my definitions: $A_n=\sum(X_i-X'_i)=B_n-B'_n$. Not sure what you mean about $X_i$; I am defining my own $X_i$ as an $\mathrm{Exp}(1/a)$ variable. That RHS is a mixture of gamma distributions (offset by $A_n$): it's a positive combination of pdfs of the form $y^{n+j}\exp(-2y/a)$ ($y=x-A_n$). We can calculate the weight coming from each $j$ then you just need to sample for fixed $j$.

Comment: @user177196: I need to go now, but will try to write a bit more about any unclear points some time.

Comment: I see your point on the RHS now. Basically, you scale it by a factor of $e^{A_n/a}$ to get the conclusion that it's a mixture of gamma distributions offset by $A_n$. Also, my OP was correct that the pdf is $\frac{1}{2a}exp(-|x|/2a)$, so $X_i$ and $X'_i$ follow $exp(\frac{1}{2a})$. Enjoy your weekend. But please elaborate on whether the sum $B_i$ is fixed (otherwise, I just need to randomly generate $i.i.d$ exponential variables $X_1,\ldots, X_n\sim exp(1/2a)$

Comment: Btw, with the new density function, I think $A_n = \frac{1}{2}(B_n - B'_{n})$, correct? Also, can you kindly help plot the density functions of the two samples, and list those two samples out so that I could compare with my implementation to make sure I get your procedure above correctly? Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Also, why do we need the weight for each $j$? So we basically do 3 sampling steps: one for $B_n$, one for $B^{-}_n$ and one for the sum of multiple Gamma distributions, which resulted in $\Gamma(n(3n-1)/2, 1/a)$? But shouldn't the last step already have all the samples generated in the previous two steps (so basically, plug in the number to get the

Comment: @user177196: I've added a bit more detail. I'm not going to go into any practical implementation, plotting, etc. Feel free to unaccept

Comment: no worries. I sincerely appreciate your help and patience with me!

Comment: so basically, do you mean we have 2 ways to sample and still get the same result (first is to just generate $n$ i.i.d random variables $X_1,\ldots X_n$ that matches with a given sum $B_n$. Second is to generate $B_n$ directly from the density function $f_{B_n|A_n}(x)$ derived above), meaning $Y_i$ and $X_i - X'_i$ share the same distribution? I tried the first way, and it resulted in normal distribution (code and figure are below)