# Sufficient statistics for family of discrete distribution

Tags: probability-theory, statistics, statistical-inference

Given $A_1, A_2,\ldots A_n$ be i.i.d random variables $\sim$ an arbitrary distribution on $\left\{1,2,3\right\}$. Define $P = $ family of discrete distributions on  $\left\{1,2,3\right\}$. Find a sufficient statistics for $P$.

**My attempt:** We define $T(\vec{A}) = A_1A_2\ldots A_n$. Let $Q\in P$, and define $Q(A_i = 1) = p_1$, $Q(A_i = 2) = p_2$ and $Q(A_i = 3) = p_3$ with $\sum_{i=1}^{3} p_i = 1$

Now, we would show: $P(\vec{A}= (a_1, a_2,\ldots, a_n)|T(\vec{A}) = t)$ is independent of $p_i$ for $i\in \left\{1,2,3\right\}$. But this is true because for any $t$ such that $T(\vec{A}=t)$, $t$ would have the form $1^{n-k-m}2^{k}3^{m}$ for some non-negative integers $k,m\leq n$ (by Unique Prime Factorization Theorem).

Therefore, $P(\vec{A}= (a_1, a_2,\ldots, a_n)|T(\vec{A}) = t) = \frac{n!p_2^k\ p_3^m\ p_1^{n-k-m}}{{n \choose k} {n-k \choose m}p_2^k\ p_3^m\ p_1^{n-k-m}} = \frac{n!}{{n \choose k} {n-k \choose m}}$ (**is this formula correct?**), which is independent of $p_1, p_2, p_3$ (1)

If no such $t$ exists for a given $\vec{A}$ where $T(\vec{A})=t$, then $P(\vec{A}= (a_1, a_2,\ldots, a_n)|T(\vec{A}) = t) = 0$, which is triviallly independent of $p_i$s (2)

From (1) and (2), $T(\vec{A}) = A_1A_2\ldots A_n$ is a sufficient statistics for $P$.

**My question:** Could anyone please help verify if my solution above is correct, particularly the formula for $P(\vec{A}= (a_1, a_2,\ldots, a_n)|T(\vec{A}) = t)$? Any thought/help would be really appreciated.

Comment: A simpler way to express a minimal sufficient statistic would be $(n_1,n_2,n_3)$ where $n_1$ is the number of ones, $n_2$ is the number of twos and $n_3$ is the number of threes. Trying to "compress" this further by encoding it into one number (or more trivially by omitting the redundant $n_3$) does nothing to make it more 'minimal' as no information about the sample is lost.

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen: great comment! But is my solution above correct? I don't need the sufficient statistic to be minimal though. But I guess my T above gave that as well?

Comment: Sorry I didn't want to try to parse what you have down and still don't (though I may feel up to it at some point). If you just need sufficient statistic without any other demands then there's an easy answer: the whole data.

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen: no problem. Although I would appreciate if you could let me know my solution is correct or not:) But anw, your suggested one is good too. I got $P(X|T(X)= (n_1, n_2, n_3)) = \frac{p_1^{n_1}p_2^{n_2}p_3^{n_3}}{n \choose n_1 p_1^n_1 ({n-n_1} \choose {n_2})p_2^n_2 p_3^n_3}$. Is this correct?

Comment: First I'll say your answer *is* a (minimal) sufficient in case that wasn't clear (although it I think you knew that and are more concerned if the details are right and I'll try to check once I'm awake). I can't read your comment to check it cause it isn't rendering right. In general, I'd suggest using the factorization theorem rather than the definition. You can also go from mine to yours by using the fact that a statistic that is a bijective function of a sufficient statistic is sufficient.

Comment: Yes, I do know that mine is a minimal sufficient, but I am more concerned about the details. Appreciate your help:)

Btw, can you try this problem as well? I am stuck on it for several hours already;p https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2471611/generating-random-sample-for-a-given-set-of-n-i-i-d-variables?noredirect=1#comment5107587_2471611

Comment: Looked at the formula. I'm not sure where the $n!$ comes from in the numerator and don't think it belongs there. (For instance your final expression looks like it's always greater than one.)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help!! I did mess up that part;p Fixed it!

Could you try part (b) of another problem here (I am quite skeptical with my final answer on that part) https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2471622/proving-a-measure-dominates-a-family-of-binomial-distribution.